# When I resize photos from my DSLR, why do they come out 500×334 instead of 500×375?

Tags: dslr, aspect-ratio

I replaced my Nikon P90 for interior work photos with a D5500 for better light control without flash.  That is working fine, but when I resize for the Web my photos are 500×334 instead of 500×375 — which my website is set up to accept.  Why?

Answer (score 6):

The sensor ratio are different:

- The [Nikon P90 sensor](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/coolpix/p/p90/spec.htm) is 4/3 (4000*3000 pixels)
- The [Nikon D5500 sensor](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/dslr/d5500/spec.htm) is 3/2 (6000*4000 pixels)

When resizing your images, you are probably fixing the length of the longest dimension of your image to 500 pixels, and the shortest dimension is computed accordingly.

- On the P90, it yields 500*375 pixels images (500/375 = 4/3)
- On the D5500, it yields 500*334 pixels images (500/333 = 3/2)

**You need to crop the D5500 images using a 4/3 image ratio.**

Comment: "You need to crop the D5500 images using a 4/3 image ratio" ...or change the website to be less restrictive

Comment: Thanks, I thought perhaps I hadn't set something correctly on the camera.